# JSON object to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

Im looking for a simple script to convert JSON objects to Javascript objects, specifically being able to make an ajax call in jQuery and then convert all of the JSON that comes back into Javascript objects for me.

I've used the mapping plugin in KnockOut.js: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output

Which nicely takes my JSON result and creates the relevant objects in knockout.

Anything currently exist to do this without knockout?

Comment: Um, `JSON.parse(...)`?

Answer (score 4):

jquery automatically does this for you.

from the JQuery documentation for [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the `dataType` setting as `'json'` in the `$.ajax` call, or use the `$.getJSON` method, and the JSON result will automatically be parsed into a Javascript object.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing here, but if you want to convert them into already defined javascript objects you need the second argument in the `JSON.parse` function.  Check MDN's documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse.
Very simple example.

```
JSON.parse(json,function(prop,val){
  if(prop==='objName'){
    new myObj(val);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

For use in JQUERY: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/
For use in simple JS: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js (look at json.js or json2.js)

Knowing that it's well-formed:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```